# Different users get the same search results

Tags: python, django, jquery-select2

The point of my question is the following. I have Django form with a field, which inherits the Selet2 field:

```
class Select2ModelField(MyBaseSelect2ModelField, AutoModelSelect2Field):
    '''
    Select2ModelField, that uses ajax to get autocomplete options. 
    Should be used by default.
    '''
    widget = Select2ChoiceWidget

class LimitedDepartmentChoiceField(Select2ModelField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LimitedDepartmentChoiceField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then I use it in my form, creating this field in a views.py, because the content of this field depends on the request data:

```
form = RepresentativeCreateEditForm(request.POST)
form.fields['department'] = LimitedDepartmentChoiceField(label=u'Department',
                                                   queryset=Department.objects.filter(
                                                             id__in=all_deps_ids))
```

The problem is that when two different users enter this page at the same time, they both have the same list of options, exactly the one which the user, who first load the page, has. And this behaviour is incorrect, they should have the different lists of options.

Please, could anyone tell me how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a value is getting set as a class attribute (somewhere, on one of your classes), rather than as an attribute of a particular instance of a class. There's a lot of inheritance going on, so you might have to do some digging to see exactly where the problem is. My guess is that it's the `Select2ChoiceWidget` class.

From your code example it looks like *all instances* of `Select2ModelField` and its subclasses are sharing a *single* `Select2ChoiceWidget` class between themselves. I would think this would be the cause of the problem.

I don't know a whole lot about the Django classes you're using, but maybe try something along these lines?

```
class Select2ModelField(MyBaseSelect2ModelField, AutoModelSelect2Field):
    '''
    Select2ModelField, that uses ajax to get autocomplete options. 
    Should be used by default.
    '''
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Not sure if this is the proper way to instantiate this class,
        # but doing so would help avoid leaking data across the instances
        # of Select2ModelField and its subclasses.
        self.widget = Select2ChoiceWidget()
        # Do the parent class(es) for good measure.
        super(Select2ModelField, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. Error is:
TypeError: 'Select2ChoiceWidget' object is not callable

     `class Select2ChoiceWidget(MySelect2BaseWidget, AutoHeavySelect2Widget):
         pass`

And here:
    `class MySelect2BaseWidget(object):

    #there goes a lot of implementation code`

Comment: Then perhaps try it with just `self.widget = Select2ChoiceWidget`? It looks like `Select2ChoiceWidget` is already an instance of something, not a class.

Comment: Well, didn't work either.( Perhaps, the solution lies not somewhere on Django level but somewhere in select2 package parameters?